# Management Objectives with no upper limit

Tags: measurement, percentage

Imagine I am working for a "fictional" company and they have given me a list of objectives to measure their managers' performance.

An example of how they are measuring them is as follows:

```
2016 Profit: $100
2017 Profit Objective: $150
2017 Profit: $170
---------
Objective Success Rate: 100%
```

The way they look at it, the Manager has surpassed both the 2016 actual profit and 2017 profit objective, so in this case would receive 100% rating on this objective as:

$$170>150>100$$

However, when we look at the companies profit margin we notice:

```
2016 Profit Margin: 25%
2017 Profit Margin Objective: 30%
2017 Profit Margin: 27.5%
---------
Objective Success Rate: 92%
```

As the Manager is under the objective, I calculate the objective success rate in this instance as:

$$27.5\% \div 30\% = 92\%$$

My issue arises when they ask me to measure the success rate of an objective with no Upper Limit. Let's take the following very real example:

```
2016 Wholesale Cost per Apple: $1.50
2017 Wholesale Cost per Apple Objective: $1.50
2017 Wholesale Cost per Apple: $4.50
```

Obviously in this case, the company wants the cost to be as low as possible. If the cost per apple is lower than objective, the success rate would be 100%, however due to no upper limit, I can't work out how to measure an unfavorable result as detailed above. Given a Cost per Apple of \$3.00 I had thought about using:

$$200\%-(\$3.00 \div \$1.50) = 0\%$$

This would mean any value double the objective would result in a success rate of 0%. However, we will clearly run into problems when the figure is more than double the objective. In the case of a CpA of \$4.50:

$$200\%-(\$4.50 \div \$1.50) = -100\%$$

This is illogical as the Manager could not have performed at less than a 0% success rate and would equate any result more than double the objective as equal.

If anyone has any ideas of how I might approach this problem, I'd be very grateful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your upper limit problem, I would simply change the logic a bit.  And, I would set as an objective a % cost reduction.  So, let's say you start at \$1.50 and your objective is \$1.25.  This would represent a cost reduction of \$1.25/\$1.50 - 1 = -17%.

So, in this case  meeting this -17% cost reduction would meet 100% of your goal.  In case, where cost do not go down but instead of up I would simply set a floor to 0% so people do not end up with a negative % of target.

Comment: Apologies, have edited the calculations.